# Choosing correct CRS to calculate distance and create buffers for datapoints in Ghana

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance, sierra-leone, ghana

I am using geographic datasets of households and mines in Ghana,Sierra Leone, and Liberia (I am analyzing each country separately). I am trying to calculate the distance between the clusters and the mines using QGIS 3.22.7. The locations are measured with latitudes and longitudes, so the layers are in WGS 84 EPSG 4326.

I have learned that it is best to reproject the layers in Projected Coordinate System first before calculating distances and buffers. For the sake of consistency and uniformity, it appears that WGS 84 UTM would be the best projection for all 3 countries. However, UTM 30N does not cover the far eastern part of Ghana, and UTM 29N only covers the eastern part of Sierra Leone. Only Liberia is fully covered by UTM 29N.

Given that UTM 30N and UTM 29N do not completely cover Ghana and Sierra Leone respectively, will there be an error/distortion when I calculate distances and buffer?

How significant is it?

What would be an alternative approach?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. You have two questions here. Please choose whether you want a country-based projection or a regional one, then do a little research on your option; at that point you'll be able to ask a more focused Question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your measurements in `EPSG:4326` were ellipsoidal and should be thus more or less accurate, based on the WGS84 ellipsoid.

As a general rule, for measurements, use either any national grid (where available) or the local UTM zone, for Ghana most of the country is within zone 30 N. Thus use `EPSG:32630` as CRS, it is based on WGS84 ellipsoid.

However, see this warning from [tcpghana.gov.gh](http://tcpghana.gov.gh/lupmis/a22_projection_and_datum.html) (the site contains more information about CRS use in Ghana, so I advice you read it):

> the only disadvantage might be a slightly higher error in the extreme
> East of the country, if zone 30 is applied on a national scale. On
> large scale, maps can easily be transferred to UTM zone 31 in these
> few areas in the extreme East to resolve this problem.

To use Ghana national grid, use [EPSG:2136](https://epsg.io/2136) than can be used for "Large and medium scale topographic mapping and engineering survey." or the more accurate [Leigon / Ghana Metre Grid, EPSG:25000](https://epsg.io/25000).

See here for more information abotu UTM projections and how to find the UTM zone of a place:

- Have a look at [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/) and type a place to get the CRS valid for this region, e.g. for [Ghana](https://epsg.io/?q=Ghana).
- To find out in what UTM zone a place is, there are several websites liek [What UTM zone am I in](https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in-#), [Apsalin.com](https://www.apsalin.com/utm-zone-finder/)
- See here for [more details about UTM projections in general](http://geokov.com/education/utm.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Babel. It seems that using UTM for all 3 countries would ensure uniformity/consistency (rather than using each country's national grid-especially since Liberia and Sierra Leone do not have a national grid in the projected coordinate system). However, not all countries are completely covered by their respective UTMs (please see my rephrased question above). Would using UTM that do not cover the whole country introduce errors in the distance calculations?

Comment: Yes, if you are working outside the relevant UTM zone, some errors will be produced. You might consider using a custom CRS. For that you might ask another question.